# Merging branch that depend on deleted file

Tags: git

Consider the following scenario of an app that has multiple versions:

1. In the `master` branch there is a code that is common for all versions of the software.
2. Based `master`, the `foo_branch` is created and it adds some new code **that is dependent on the code from `master`**.
3. Based on `master`, the `bar_branch` is created and it adds some new code, but **it doesn't need the original code from master**, so deletes it.
4. The two versions of the software should join together into a new branch. So I simply create `new_branch`, based on `foo_branch` and then merge `bar_branch` into it.

Repo:

```
*   51f1ddb (HEAD -> new_branch) Merge branch 'bar_branch' into new_branch
|\
| * c68a5b3 (bar_branch) add code to bar branch
| * f550e6d delete common code
* | 0ec00c9 (foo_branch) add code to foo branch
|/
* d8d13c7 (master) add common code
```

Problem is that now the original code from master is deleted, but the code from `foo_branch` depends on it.

How do I address this issue? What are the options? I was thinking that it would be very helpful, if the merge created a conflict whenever something is deleted. Is this possible?

Comment: Does the `bar_branch` have distinct commits for the deletion(s)? If so, I think you can use cherry-picking to merge the branches in the way you want.

Comment: “… it would be very helpful if the merge created a conflict whenever something is deleted” – for this, one of Git’s built-in [merge strategies](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies) might work, or you can [implement a custom merge driver](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver) that exits with a non-zero exit status when it sees that files were deleted.